# How many reactors does the Death Star have?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, death-star

The movie and novelization of Rogue One indicate that the destruction of both Jedha City and the Scarif complex required but a "single reactor ignition". So how many reactors does it take for the Death Star to fire a full blast?

(Actually, the "[Explore](http://www.starwars.com/rogue-one/explore/)" option on the Rogue One official website seems to indicate that there is only one reactor - called a "hypermatter reactor".)

So is there any explanation?

Comment: It always has at least 1 too many.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication seems to be not that the station has multiple reactors (all signs point to it having a single main reactor) but that they're referring to the amount of energy output from the hypermatter reactor itself.

Note that they use a series of [baffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baffle_(heat_transfer)) to reduce the amount of radiation, and hence power being generated by the main reactor. This presumably is what they mean by using a single reactor.

> *“Target Jedha City,” he snapped. “Prepare single reactor ignition.”*
>
> *Krennic concealed his resentment, calmed himself with the sounds of
> his breath and the tidal rush of the station reactor. This wasn’t how
> he’d imagined the culmination of twenty years’ work—a diminished
> attack, a grand moff’s power play—but it was the reality he contended
> with.*
>
> ...
>
> *KRENNIC PACED THE OVERBRIDGE UNDER Tarkin’s watch, observing the
> technicians and referencing every step against the control protocols
> he’d memorized long ago. Levers were flipped, rotating focusing lenses
> deep within the station’s core. **Engineers adjusted radiation baffles
> and ventilation pumps as the main reactor shook with effort and its
> comforting roar turned to an eerie scream.** Krennic saw more than one
> hand shaking, more than one face flushed or daubed with sweat. But his
> officers knew their duty. They would do everything necessary to
> destroy Jedha City at the bidding of their commander.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: So, then, perhaps 'single reactor ignition' doesn't mean there's a single *reactor*, but rather a single *ignition*?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - Very possibly. Honestly it's not clear.

Comment: I suppose this is on par with their measuring a time in parsecs.  Still, as an engineer, if anyone confused a baffle for a reactor, I'd take great effort to make sure they weren't anywhere near a control for the death star, nor in a command position.