# What gives the Death Star its firepower?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

Considering that in *The Force Awakens* we see that Starkiller Base needs to drain a star to power it, what makes the Death Star so powerful? It's a giant superlaser, but what does it run on?

Comment: Just a mention, DS could shoot only in the same system/orbit with LOS. Starkiller Base was able to take out a target **ANYWHERE IN THE GALAXY** shooting through hyperspace. That's gotta need tons (sic) of energy. Comparing the two superweapons energy requirements is not easy.

Comment: The lost orb of phantasia! Jk..

Comment: Kyber crystals anyone? (Rogue one)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A [Hypermatter Reactor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hypermatter_reactor). Just like Star Destroyers and other imperial vessels, but bigger (obviously).

> Many of those present were researchers and scientists involved with various aspects of the battle station project — the drives, shield and tractor beam technology, **hypermatter power plant** — without a full understanding of what they were working on.
>   <sub>*[Catalyst](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Catalyst:_A_Rogue_One_Novel) - Chapter 8: Public Displays of Affection*</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The [superlaser](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star#Armaments_and_defensive_systems) was fired by taking the power from the hypermatter reactor and focusing it all through the kyber crystals.

Comment: Relevant: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150709/how-many-reactors-does-the-death-star-have

Comment: Interesting, I remember one of the purportedly scrapped Clone Wars story arcs (due to the series' cancellation) was about tracking down a giant kyber crystal and wondering what it was for.

Comment: Will we see those arcs again now that the clone wars has been completed?